# Dynamic value of HTML5 progress bar upon button click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to update the value of a HTML5 progress bar upon entering a value in a text area and clicking a button. I'm assuming that I will only be entering properly formatted integer numbers in the text area.

Here is the html:

```
<textarea id="txt" cols=20 rows=1 placeholder="Enter total time"></textarea>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Save</button>
<progress id="pr"></progress>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
function myFunction()
{
var value = document.getElementById('txt').value;
document.getElementsByTagName("PROGRESS").setAttribute("value",value.parseInt());
};
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

PS: This is my first post here, how do I make the code all colorful and pretty?

Edit: Seems like the code became colorful all by itself :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things: You were missing a range for the bar and `getElementsByTagName` returns an array like object.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var value = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  document.getElementsByTagName("PROGRESS")[0].setAttribute("value", value);
}
```

```html
<input id="txt" placeholder="Enter total time">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Save</button>
<br/>
<progress id="pr" max="100"></progress>
```

Comment: The fiddle doesn't seem to work with your amended code. The progress bar remains at the default initial value.

Comment: It doesn't work in JSFiddle, but does work in W3School's HTML editor.

Comment: @CodeWalker Fiddle had wrapper around the function, updated Fiddle to No wrap.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Could you explain what changing to "No Wrap" did? This still doesn't work on my actual webpage where I have the script in the body, so what could I do to make it "No Wrap" there?

Comment: Having the script in the body is just fine. jsFiddle wraps code by default so it wasn't accessible in the [global scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong code for this. value is not any object to call parseInt() function.

Using getElementsByTagName you will get array for DOM elements.
Below is the changes in your code:

```
function myFunction()
{
var value = document.getElementById('txt').value;
document.getElementsByTagName("PROGRESS")[0].setAttribute("value",parseInt(value));
};


<textarea id="txt" cols=20 rows=1 placeholder="Enter total time"></textarea>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Save</button>
<progress id="pr"></progress>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. I am trying to enter the value "10" in the text area but the progress bar remains at the initial default value.

Comment: Are you putting quotes around 10? working for me may be you are missing something.

Comment: also put document.getElementsByTagName("PROGRESS")[0].setAttribute("max","100"); just before the function close.

Comment: I'm perplexed, it doesn't work in JSFiddle or my page, but does work in W3School's HTML editor.

Comment: in JSFiddle it give an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined